# How can I determine the available amount of disk space when using a charm?

Tags: mysql, juju, postgresql, amazon-ec2, storage

When using juju to deploy a DB, how can I determine the available amount of disk space when using the DB charm? Suppose that I'm using EC2 (or anywhere else) to deploy a PostgreSQL/MySQL/WhateverDB charm... Where will the actual database data be stored? Will the charm create a EBS volume and attach it to the instance and put the data there? What if my database is very large? Or very small? Where can I determine the size of the available storage?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ec2, every instance gets an 8G EBS volume by default; if you need more you can [specify](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/charms-constraints.html) the `root-disk` [constraint](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/reference-constraints.html) on the service. (Note that this will only apply to new units of the service, though.)

You can't generally control where the database you deploy keeps its data -- that's up to the charm author -- but it *will* generally be on that root disk ;). To determine the size of the disk, you should be able to check the hardware characteristics of the deployed machine in `juju status`; if that data is missing on any given provider, that's a bug and we would appreciate a [report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+filebug).

We will be working on more sophisticated storage management for juju sometime shortly after the release of 14.04.